# Can we automate "Call Receiving" feature in android?

Tags: android, automation, appium, robotframework, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to automate calling features in android using robot framework + appiumLibrary.

What I've done so far?
I am able to dial a number using these steps :

```
  Step 1.
  Open Application  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub   platformName=Android   platformVersion=5.0.1   deviceName=4a119f6b  appPackage=com.android.contacts    appActivity=com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity


  Step 2. AppiumLibrary.Click Element    name=Keypad
```

After this I clicked on each number one by one and then clicked on dial button.

Where am I stuck?

In similar fashion I am trying to automate Call receiving feature. I'm dialing from some other phone on connected device and while phone is ringing I'm trying to capture screenshot of xml using uiautomatorviewer.
It is not capturing it.

Is it the right approach?? Is there any other way to automate this functionality?

Comment: What error are u getting when you are trying to capture the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your screen mode when you receive it:

- If the screen is asleep, i.e., when a call is received it opens the activity to deal with the call, then you can detect what is the package on the screen and match it with the package of the call activity.
- If the screen is awake, i.e., when a call is received you see like a small pop up on the top of the screen with the "Answer/Reject" options, then UiAutomatorViewer can't detect them. I don't know if Appium can detect it or not, but I suppose it can't (UiAutomator can't for instance, it can only detect what UiAutomatorViewer detects).

In summary, if a new app is opened, you can detect it is the call app. Otherwise, the "popup" isn't detectable.